# How to get the values of buttons with eventListener?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I created buttons with different values in my HTML. I am trying to output these values when clicked on. I am making use of `querySelectorAll` and eventListeners but it keeps outputing undefined.

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
function showNumber() {
  if (buttons.value != 5) {
    document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML = buttons.value;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML = 5;
  }
}
buttons.forEach(buttons => {
  buttons.addEventListener("click", () => {
    showNumber()
  });
});
```

Comment: In general it is best practice to not name the inner variable of a forEach loop the same as the Array. ```buttons.forEach(button=>{...``` Also, it would be helpful if you have some html as part of your example.

Comment: Your showNumber function should receive an [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) and you should use its target's properties to get the information you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
const
  buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button"),
  screen = document.getElementById('screen');

Array.from(buttons).forEach(button =>
  button.addEventListener("click", showNumber));

function showNumber(event) { // Listener can access its triggering event
  const button = event.target; // event's `target` property is useful
  if (button.value != 5) { screen.innerHTML = button.value; }
  else { screen.innerHTML = 5; }
}
```

```html
<button value="5">Button 1</button>
<button value="42">Button 2</button>

<p id="screen"></p>
```

But you might consider employing [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation):

```js
const
  container = document.getElementById('container'),
  screen = document.getElementById('screen');
container.addEventListener("click", showNumber); // events bubble up to ancestors

function showNumber(event) {
  const clickedThing = event.target;
  if(clickedThing.tagName == 'BUTTON'){ // makes sure this click interests us
    screen.innerHTML = clickedThing.value;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <button value="5">Button 1</button>
  <button value="42">Button 2</button>
</div>

<p id="screen"></p>
```

Answer (score 3):

in your foreach loop you need to pass back the button to your function

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
function showNumber(button) {

  if (button.value != 6) {
    document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML = button.value;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML = 5;
  }
}


buttons.forEach(button => {

  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    showNumber(button)
  });
});
```

```html
<button value=10>10</button>
<button value=8>8</button>
<button value=6>6</button>
<button value=4>4</button>
<button value=2>2</button>

<div id='screen'></div>
```

Comment: Not the "cleanest", but surely the quickest fix to OP's code.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `buttons` is *the whole array* of buttons, not just the clicked button.

To access the button that was clicked, the simplest way is to use `this`. Inside an event handler, `this` points to the element that triggered the event (i.e. the button that was clicked), **as long as** we bind the function `showNumber` directly to the event handler (and not calling `showNumber()` from an anonymous function like in your initial code), i.e.:

```
button.addEventListener("click", showNumber);
```

So, binding `showNumber` directly to the event handler and using `this`, this is what we can do:

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
function showNumber() {
  document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML = this.value;
}
buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener("click", showNumber);
});
```

```html
<p id="screen"></p>
<button value="1">1</button>
<button value="10">10</button>
```

---

Edit: Removed unnecessary if statement inside the `showNumber` function.